# How to Add TinyMCE's plugin in wordpress?

Tags: plugins, tinymce, plugin-tinymce

I had found a [TinyMCE's plugin](https://github.com/zotonic/zotonic/blame/bfce59c23f18065db7d1a53296a020472cb2e219/modules/mod_base/lib/js/modules/tinymce3.4.3.2/plugins/zbdo/editor_plugin.js) that change the direction of selected text. How to add this plugin in wordpress? Any one guide me?

I had tried to add it in `/wp-includes/tinymce/plugin/custom-dir/plugin.js` but what to do next to register it with wordpress. Its basic question but I am new to Wordpress. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can register TinyMCE plugins using [`mce_external_plugins`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/mce_external_plugins) filter:

```
add_filter('mce_external_plugins', 'my_tinymce_plugins');
function my_tinymce_plugins() {
    $plugins_array = array(
                         'my-tinymce-plugin-name' => 'tinymce-plugin-url-of-js-file'
                     );
    return $plugins_array;
}
```

You can add that code to functions.php file of your theme, or better in a WordPress plugin to make it theme independent.

Also, I recommend to not upload externa tinymce plugins to wp-include `/wp-includes/tinymce/` folder; use a WordPress plugin or theme folder instead.

For example, I've made this test. I've created a file called editor_plugin.js with the content of the TinyMCE plugin js file. I've uploaded it to my theme root folder and I've added this code to functions.php:

```
add_filter('mce_external_plugins', 'my_tinymce_plugins');
function my_tinymce_plugins() {
    $plugins_array = array(
                          'zbdo' => get_template_directory_uri().'/editor_plugin.js'
                     );
    return $plugins_array;
}
```

Comment: Much thanks for answer. Please guide me some more that what is 'my-tinymce-plugin-name' means? name of js plugin file?

Comment: It is usually the same of js plugin file but not always. In fact, you can set whatever you want as name. The only thing you must know that this name is used to handle the script enqueue. I recommend to use the exact name given by the plugin developer.

Comment: I had tried 'tiny' (filename), 'zbdo', 'Zotonic Inline Text Direction Plugin', 'ZotonicBdoPlugin' as plugin names (these found in [plugin](https://github.com/zotonic/zotonic/blame/bfce59c23f18065db7d1a53296a020472cb2e219/modules/mod_base/lib/js/modules/tinymce3.4.3.2/plugins/zbdo/editor_plugin.js)) but its not working. Visual Editor completely goes blank & un-editable. Whats wrong?

Comment: This code works. I've tested it. See the edited answer with my example test. The plugin is correctly added to TinyMCE, that doesn't mean that the TinyMCE plugin works correctly. It is correctly loaded but if it doesn't work you have to talk with the plugin developer as there is nothing we can do here with his/her work.

Comment: you are right. But I still not understand, when I remove '/' from '/editor_plugin.js', it will remove all things of editor? Why?

Comment: If the URL is incorrect, as it is if you remove "/", it generates a 404 error ("Not found") and it seems to generate a error in the script that loads TinyMCE plugins.